# to_gbq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'location'

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

The problem is it saying there an unexpected keyword, but there is non keyword in df.to_gbq(destination_table="********", project_id="********", if_exists="replace")

Any, ideas on how to fix this issues are welcomed, I am running this in Jupiter notebook. But I am can't run the function when I do it say there is an unexpected keyword 'location'

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import re
import datetime
import time

humans = [
 {'name':'Tom', 'gender': 'M'},
 {'name':'Bob', 'gender': 'M'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(humans)

df.to_gbq(destination_table="random.humans", project_id="top-secret", if_exists="replace")
```

```
<ipython-input-19-dae3425a89d7> in <module>()
----> 1 result.to_gbq(destination_table="random.humans", project_id="top-secret", if_exists="replace")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_gbq(self, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, reauth, if_exists, auth_local_webserver, table_schema, location, progress_bar, credentials, verbose, private_key)
   1426             table_schema=table_schema, location=location,
   1427             progress_bar=progress_bar, credentials=credentials,
-> 1428             verbose=verbose, private_key=private_key)
   1429 
   1430     @classmethod

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, reauth, if_exists, auth_local_webserver, table_schema, location, progress_bar, credentials, verbose, private_key)
    160         auth_local_webserver=auth_local_webserver, table_schema=table_schema,
    161         location=location, progress_bar=progress_bar,
--> 162         credentials=credentials, verbose=verbose, private_key=private_key)

TypeError: to_gbq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'location'
```

Package info:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py36_0  
_py-xgboost-mutex         2.0                       cpu_0    conda-forge
_tflow_1100_select        0.0.3                       mkl  
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu  
absl-py                   0.5.0                    py36_0  
alabaster                 0.7.11                   py36_0  
altgraph                  0.15                       py_0    conda-forge
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py36_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.2                    py36_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py36_0  
appdirs                   1.4.3            py36h28b3542_0  
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0  
astor                     0.7.1                    py36_0  
astroid                   2.0.4                    py36_0  
astropy                   3.0.4            py36h14c3975_0  
atomicwrites              1.2.1                    py36_0  
attrs                     18.2.0           py36h28b3542_0  
autograd                  1.2                        py_1    conda-forge
automat                   0.7.0                    py36_0  
autopep8                  1.4                      py36_0  
babel                     2.6.0                    py36_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py36_0  
backports                 1.0                      py36_1  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py36_2  
bcrypt                    3.1.6            py36h7b6447c_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.6.3                    py36_0  
bitarray                  0.8.3            py36h14c3975_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py36_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
blaze                     0.11.3                   py36_0  
bleach                    2.1.4                    py36_0  
blinker                   1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
blosc                     1.14.4               hdbcaa40_0  
bokeh                     0.13.0                   py36_0  
boto                      2.49.0                   py36_0  
boto3                     1.9.82                     py_0  
botocore                  1.12.82                    py_0  
bottleneck                1.2.1            py36h035aef0_1  
bzip2                     1.0.6                h14c3975_5  
ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0  
cachetools                2.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.14.12              h8948797_3  
certifi                   2019.3.9                 py36_0  
cffi                      1.11.5           py36he75722e_1  
chardet                   3.0.4                    py36_1  
click                     6.7                      py36_0  
cloudpickle               0.5.6                    py36_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py36_1  
colorama                  0.3.9                    py36_0  
conda                     4.6.12                   py36_1  
conda-build               3.15.1                   py36_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
constantly                15.1.0           py36h28b3542_0  
contextlib2               0.5.5                    py36_0  
cryptography              2.3.1            py36hc365091_0  
cryptography-vectors      2.3.1                 py36_1000    conda-forge/label/cf201901
cudatoolkit               9.0                  h13b8566_0  
cudnn                     7.1.2                 cuda9.0_0  
cupti                     9.0.176                       0  
curl                      7.61.0               h84994c4_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py36_0  
cyrus-sasl                2.1.26               hf938e8d_3  
cython                    0.28.5           py36hf484d3e_0  
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py36h14c3975_1  
dask                      0.19.2                   py36_0  
dask-core                 0.19.2                   py36_0  
datashape                 0.5.4                    py36_1  
dbus                      1.13.2               h714fa37_1  
decorator                 4.3.0                    py36_0  
defusedxml                0.5.0                    py36_1  
distributed               1.23.2                   py36_0  
docutils                  0.14                     py36_0  
entrypoints               0.2.3                    py36_2  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py36_0  
expat                     2.2.6                he6710b0_0  
fastcache                 1.0.2            py36h14c3975_2  
ffmpeg                    4.0                  hcdf2ecd_0  
filelock                  3.0.8                    py36_0  
flask                     1.0.2                    py36_1  
flask-caching             1.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
flask-cors                3.0.6                    py36_0  
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0  
freeglut                  3.0.0                hf484d3e_5  
freetype                  2.9.1                h8a8886c_1  
fribidi                   1.0.5                h7b6447c_0  
future                    0.17.1                py36_1000    conda-forge
gast                      0.2.0                    py36_0  
gensim                    3.4.0            py36h14c3975_0  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                haa9412d_0  
gevent                    1.3.6            py36h7b6447c_0  
glib                      2.56.2               hd408876_0  
glob2                     0.6                      py36_1  
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py36h10f8cd9_2  
google-api-core           0.1.4                      py_0    conda-forge
google-api-python-client  1.7.6                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.6.1                      py_0    conda-forge
google-auth-httplib2      0.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.1.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
google-cloud              0.34.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-bigquery     0.29.0                     py_0    conda-forge
google-cloud-core         0.28.1                     py_0    conda-forge
google-cloud-sdk          228.0.0               py36_1000    conda-forge
google-cloud-storage      1.13.0                     py_0    conda-forge
google-resumable-media    0.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
googleapis-common-protos  1.5.5                      py_0    conda-forge
graphite2                 1.3.12               h23475e2_2  
graphviz                  2.40.1               h21bd128_2  
greenlet                  0.4.15           py36h7b6447c_0  
grpcio                    1.12.1           py36hdbcaa40_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1  
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1  
h5py                      2.8.0            py36h989c5e5_3  
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hffaf4a1_0  
hdf5                      1.10.2               hba1933b_1  
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py36_2  
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py36_0  
httplib2                  0.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
hyperlink                 18.0.0                   py36_0  
icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1  
idna                      2.7                      py36_0  
imageio                   2.4.1                    py36_0  
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py36_0  
incremental               17.5.0                   py36_0  
intel-openmp              2019.0                      118  
ipykernel                 4.10.0                   py36_0  
ipython                   6.5.0                    py36_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0  
ipywidgets                7.4.2                    py36_0  
isort                     4.3.4                    py36_0  
itsdangerous              0.24                     py36_1  
jasper                    2.0.14               h07fcdf6_1  
jbig                      2.1                  hdba287a_0  
jdcal                     1.4                      py36_0  
jedi                      0.12.1                   py36_0  
jeepney                   0.4                      py36_0  
jinja2                    2.10                     py36_0  
jmespath                  0.9.3                    py36_0  
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2  
jsonschema                2.6.0                    py36_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_7  
jupyter_client            5.2.3                    py36_0  
jupyter_console           5.2.0                    py36_1  
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py36_0  
jupyterlab                0.34.9                   py36_0  
jupyterlab_launcher       0.13.1                   py36_0  
keras                     2.2.2                         0  
keras-applications        1.0.6                    py36_0  
keras-base                2.2.2                    py36_0  
keras-preprocessing       1.0.5                    py36_0  
keyring                   13.2.1                   py36_0  
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py36hf484d3e_0  
krb5                      1.16.1               hc83ff2d_6  
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36h14c3975_2  
libcurl                   7.61.0               h1ad7b7a_0  
libdb                     6.1.26               he6710b0_0  
libedit                   3.1.20170329         h6b74fdf_2  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc                    7.2.0                h69d50b8_2  
libgcc-ng                 8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libglu                    9.0.0                hf484d3e_1  
libntlm                   1.5                  h7b6447c_0  
libopencv                 3.4.2                hb342d67_1  
libopus                   1.3                  h7b6447c_0  
libpng                    1.6.36               hbc83047_0    anaconda
libprotobuf               3.6.0                hdbcaa40_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0  
libssh2                   1.8.0                h9cfc8f7_4  
libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libtiff                   4.0.9                he85c1e1_2  
libtool                   2.4.6                h544aabb_3  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2  
libvpx                    1.7.0                h439df22_0  
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1  
libxgboost                0.80                 hfc679d8_1    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.8                h26e45fe_1  
libxslt                   1.1.32               h1312cb7_0  
lifelines                 0.16.1                     py_0    conda-forge/label/cf201901
llvmlite                  0.24.0           py36hdbcaa40_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py36_1  
lxml                      4.2.5            py36hefd8a0e_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h49e0be7_2  
macholib                  1.11                       py_0    conda-forge
markdown                  2.6.11                   py36_0  
markupsafe                1.0              py36h14c3975_1  
matplotlib                3.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py36_1  
mecab                     0.996                         1    chezou
mecab-python3             0.996.1                  pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.3            py36h14c3975_1  
mkl                       2019.1                      144    anaconda
mkl-service               1.1.2            py36he904b0f_5    anaconda
mkl_fft                   1.0.10           py36ha843d7b_0    anaconda
mkl_random                1.0.2            py36hd81dba3_0    anaconda
more-itertools            4.3.0                    py36_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h10f8cd9_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                hdf1c602_3  
mpmath                    1.0.0                    py36_2  
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py36h6bb024c_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py36_0  
mysql                     5.7.22               hef7e34c_0  
mysql-connector-c         6.1.11               hf4847fb_0  
mysql-connector-python    8.0.13           py36h9c95fcb_0    anaconda
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py36_0  
nbconvert                 5.4.0                    py36_1  
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py36_0  
nccl                      1.3.5                 cuda9.0_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  hf484d3e_0  
networkx                  2.1                      py36_0  
ninja                     1.8.2            py36h6bb024c_1  
nltk                      3.3.0                    py36_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py36_2  
notebook                  5.6.0                    py36_0  
numba                     0.39.0           py36h04863e7_0  
numexpr                   2.6.9            py36h9e4a6bb_0    anaconda
numpy                     1.15.4           py36h7e9f1db_0    anaconda
numpy-base                1.15.4           py36hde5b4d6_0    anaconda
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py36_0  
oauthlib                  2.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
odo                       0.5.1                    py36_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py36_0  
opencv                    3.4.2            py36h6fd60c2_1  
openpyxl                  2.5.8                    py36_0  
openssl                   1.0.2r               h7b6447c_0  
packaging                 17.1                     py36_0  
pandas                    0.24.2           py36he6710b0_0  
pandas-compat             0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pandas-gbq                0.4.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hea2e7c5_1  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py36_1  
pango                     1.42.4               h049681c_0  
parso                     0.3.1                    py36_0  
partd                     0.3.8                    py36_0  
patchelf                  0.9                  hf484d3e_2  
path.py                   11.1.0                   py36_0  
pathlib2                  2.3.2                    py36_0  
patsy                     0.5.0                    py36_0  
pcre                      8.42                 h439df22_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py36_0  
pexpect                   4.6.0                    py36_0  
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py36_0  
pillow                    5.3.0            py36h34e0f95_0  
pip                       10.0.1                   py36_0  
pixman                    0.34.0               hceecf20_3  
pkginfo                   1.4.2                    py36_1  
pluggy                    0.7.1            py36h28b3542_0  
ply                       3.11                     py36_0  
prometheus_client         0.3.1            py36h28b3542_0  
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15                   py36_0  
protobuf                  3.6.0            py36hf484d3e_0  
psutil                    5.4.7            py36h14c3975_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py36_0  
py                        1.6.0                    py36_0  
py-opencv                 3.4.2            py36hb342d67_1  
py-xgboost                0.80             py36hfc679d8_1    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.4.4            py36h28b3542_0  
pyasn1-modules            0.2.2                    py36_0  
pycodestyle               2.4.0                    py36_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py36h14c3975_0  
pycparser                 2.19                     py36_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py36h14c3975_9  
pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py36hb7f436b_0  
pydot                     1.3.0                    py36_1  
pyflakes                  2.0.0                    py36_0  
pygments                  2.2.0                    py36_0  
pyinstaller               3.4              py36ha92aebf_0    conda-forge
pyjwt                     1.6.4                      py_0    conda-forge
pylint                    2.1.1                    py36_0  
pymongo                   3.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pyodbc                    4.0.24           py36he6710b0_0  
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py36_0  
pyparsing                 2.2.1                    py36_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h05f1152_2  
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py36_0  
pytables                  3.4.4            py36ha205bf6_0  
pytest                    3.8.1                    py36_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.2              py36h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.4.0                    py36_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.1.3                    py36_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.3.0                    py36_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.0                    py36_0  
python                    3.6.6                h6e4f718_2  
python-dateutil           2.7.3                    py36_0  
python_http_client        3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pytorch                   0.4.1            py36ha74772b_0    anaconda
pytz                      2018.5                   py36_0  
pywavelets                1.0.0            py36hdd07704_0  
pyyaml                    3.13             py36h14c3975_0  
pyzmq                     17.1.2           py36h14c3975_0  
qt                        5.9.6                h8703b6f_2  
qtawesome                 0.5.0                    py36_0  
qtconsole                 4.4.1                    py36_0  
qtpy                      1.5.1                    py36_0  
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
requests                  2.19.1                   py36_0  
requests-oauthlib         0.8.0                    py36_1    conda-forge
rope                      0.11.0                   py36_0  
rsa                       4.0                      pypi_0    pypi
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py36h14c3975_0  
s3transfer                0.1.13                   py36_0  
scikit-image              0.14.0           py36hf484d3e_1  
scikit-learn              0.20.2           py36hd81dba3_0    anaconda
scipy                     1.2.0            py36h7c811a0_0    anaconda
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py36_0  
secretstorage             3.1.0                    py36_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0  
sendgrid                  5.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
service_identity          17.0.0           py36h28b3542_0  
setuptools                40.2.0                   py36_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py36_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py36hf484d3e_0  
six                       1.11.0                   py36_1  
smart_open                1.8.0                    py36_0  
snappy                    1.1.7                hbae5bb6_3  
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py36_0  
sortedcollections         1.0.1                    py36_0  
sortedcontainers          2.0.5                    py36_0  
sphinx                    1.8.1                    py36_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py36_1  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                    py36_1  
spyder                    3.3.1                    py36_1  
spyder-kernels            0.2.6                    py36_0  
sqlalchemy                1.2.12           py36h7b6447c_0  
sqlite                    3.26.0               h7b6447c_0    anaconda
statsmodels               0.9.0            py36h035aef0_0  
sympy                     1.3                      py36_0  
tblib                     1.3.2                    py36_0  
tensorboard               1.12.0           py36hf484d3e_0  
tensorflow                1.12.0          gpu_py36he68c306_0  
tensorflow-base           1.12.0          gpu_py36h8e0ae2d_0  
tensorflow-gpu            1.12.0               h0d30ee6_0    anaconda
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py36_1  
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1  
testpath                  0.3.1                    py36_0  
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
toolz                     0.9.0                    py36_0  
tornado                   5.1.1            py36h7b6447c_0  
tqdm                      4.26.0           py36h28b3542_0  
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py36_0  
twisted                   18.7.0           py36h14c3975_1  
typed-ast                 1.1.0            py36h14c3975_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py36_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h14c3975_0  
uritemplate               3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.23                     py36_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py36_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py36_1  
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0  
wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    py36_0  
wrapt                     1.10.11          py36h14c3975_2  
xgboost                   0.80             py36hfc679d8_1    conda-forge
xlrd                      1.1.0                    py36_1  
xlsxwriter                1.1.1                    py36_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py36_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2  
zeromq                    4.2.5                hf484d3e_1  
zict                      0.1.3                    py36_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               ha838bed_2  
zope                      1.0                      py36_1  
zope.interface            4.5.0            py36h14c3975_0
```

I tried switching to another version of python with conda I was 3.8.6 now I am 3.6.6. I also try to switch pandas versions

Comment: Please add a minimum working replication of the error you get. It harder for people inexperienced with the library to replicate the problem with the one line you posted.

Comment: I am uploading to google bigquery using to_gbq() , there is no sql

Comment: I had this same issue when upgrading Pandas, the location field was new in version 0.5.0 of pandas-gbq. Have you tried running your code in an older version?

Comment: Also, have you tried explicitly adding the expected location argument, as per the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it with the magic of downgrading pandas-gbq to 0.8.0 , I had some conflict with pandas and pandas-gbq